# What is the second "Select 3D Acceleration" option?

Tags: omikron-the-nomad-soul

I started up my Steam copy of *Omikron: The Nomad Soul* and was tinkering with the settings like matching my screen resolution, setting everything on high as the last time i played it was years ago before i got my current PC (which is way more powerful than my previous PC which i played Omikon on)

I went to change my **Select 3D Acceleration** which is currently set as **Primary Display Driver** but when i changed this the screen went black and going <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> and getting into Task Manager it said that it had stopped responding.

Obviously whatever the second option was isn't something i should use but since the screen went black i don't know what it was. so i am wondering what is the second "Select 3D Acceleration" option?

Comment: Is this like a drop down list option? Or something you toggle with like an arrow button? I assume the latter since you didn't list what the name of the second option is.  It could possible be trying to find another display device like a second graphics card, and when it can't find it, it makes the screen black.

Comment: @TimmyJim yeh it's more or less how the arrow button select would work except you have to press enter